# how to convert cloudant query to nano search

Tags: search, cloudant, nano

I have this query in cloudant database, but backend use  var db = nano.db.use(process.env.DB_NAME || ''); which doesn't support db.find but support db.search. how could I convert this query to a search parameter?

```
var queryPifLog = {
        "selector": {
            "type": "piflog",
            "supplier_name": "1234",
            "region": {
                "$in": [
                    "ANZ",
                    "GCG"
                ]
            },
            "assign_datetime":{
                "$gt":assignedDate
            },
            "closure_datetime":{
                "$lt": closedData
            },

            "pif_owner": {
                "$in": [
                    "haha@163.com"
                ]
            }
        },
        "fields": [
            "operation",
            "operator",
            "type",
            "region",
            "country",
            "supplier_name",
            "operation_time",
            "pif_owner"
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The nano library supports `db.find` so it's fine to use that. See documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#dbfindselector-callback

If you were to use Cloudant Search, then you'd have to use its Lucene-based query language. The Cloudant Search equivalent of the above query would be something like

```
q=type:piflog AND supplier_name:1234 AND (region:ANZ OR region:GCG) AND assign_datetime:(2018-01-01 TO *) AND closedData:(* TO 2018-10-22) AND pif_owner:haha@163.com
```

assuming you have indexed the fields appropriately.